# Windows 7 Group Policy to display message for login tries left before account lock

Tags: active-directory, ldap, windows-server-2008

My requirement is to display the the remaining count left on the login screen when user trying to login using Windows 7 OS before account lock in case user enter invalid password. 
I am having Active Directory on Windows 2008 R2 server.  I set the maximum Lockout count  = 5 in  GPO policy.

**Example:** If user try login first 1 attempt is failed, next time enter password and login shold show message for remaining attemps left.( my case count 4 left)

Please let me know as this is urgent for me.

---

If you read from the AD attributes then how do you display the remaining login count left message when user type wrong password in the Windows Login screen.

As Windows Login screen we don't have control over the login screen. So in this how to display message there.

Any idea. 
vivek

Comment: This information can be read from directory attributes or log entries if you can determine which domain controller the user was trying to log in to.. but how do you plan on modifying the default login display to show that information?

Answer (score 1):

As of Windows Vista, so Windows 7 is also affected, Microsoft rewrote the login environment for Windows to reduce what could be displayed there. In Windows 2000 and Windows XP there were methods to display the information you require. Those were removed with Vista.

To the best of my knowledge, this is not possible with Windows 7.